# Adjuntar archivo PDF a email android API 24

Tags: java, android

Soy muy novato en esto, resulta que tengo una app que me enviará a mi gmail todos los datos y un adjunto para enviarlo por email, pero al actualizar el móvil a android 8 ya no me adjunta el archivo, he puesto un condicional dependiendo de la API pero me manda todos los datos menos el adjunto al gmail y no se por que no puede adjuntarlo, el archivo esta en la ubicación correcta.

```
public void enviarbaja1(){


    String pdfFile= String.valueOf(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Bajas/","Baja " + Variables.getentradanombretomadorbaja() + ".pdf" ));


    Uri uri;
    //Validación de acuerdo al OS.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        uri =Uri.parse(pdfFile);

    } else{
        uri =Uri.fromFile((new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Bajas/","Baja " + Variables.getentradanombretomadorbaja() + ".pdf" )));
    }

   //Instanciamos un Intent del tipo ACTION_SEND
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    //Aqui definimos la tipologia de datos del contenido dle Email en este caso text/html
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");

    // Indicamos con un Array de tipo String las direcciones de correo a las cuales enviar
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emaildestino1.getText().toString()});

    // Aqui definimos un email para enviar como copia
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{emailcopia1.getText().toString()});

    // Aqui definimos un titulo para el Email
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, emailtitulo1.getText().toString());

    // Aqui definimos un Asunto para el Email
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailasunto1.getText().toString());

    // Aqui obtenemos la referencia al texto y lo pasamos al Email Intent
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailcuerpo1.getText().toString());

    // Colocamos el adjunto en el stream
   emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);


    //indicamos el tipo de dato
    emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");


    try {
        //Enviamos el Correo iniciando una nueva Activity con el emailIntent.
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Seleccionar metodo de envio..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(generarpdfbaja.this, "No hay ninguna aplicación de correo electrónico instalada.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Me parece un problema de permisos, apartir de la api 24 se hicieron algunos cambios con respectoa estos. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=es-419

Comment: muchas gracias, mirare el enlace y vere a ver si le saco punta

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar FileProvider
Uri uri= Uri.parse(String.valueOf(FileProvider.getUriForFile(PdfView.this, PdfView.this.getPackageName() + ".provider",file)));